# How to calculate sums for all fields in a table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-database, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [are there any methods can choose all field and make the SUM for each fields or I must do it one by one?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22255/are-there-any-methods-can-choose-all-field-and-make-the-sum-for-each-fields-or-i)

Are there any methods that can calculate the summary statistic table for all the fields existing in a table with summary type  **SUM**

I have a feature class with about 300 fields and I need an automatic method to sum all these fields once or must I choose one by one?